# Tiddly Wiki tags list like in Tiddly Wiki Classic

Tags: tiddlywiki

In Tiddly Wiki classic I had a list with all Tiddlers tagged with the tag like the tiddlers name.

Example:
I had a tiddler named "Intro".
When I have opened the tiddler "Intro" I got a gray box with all tiddlers which had the tag "Intro".
For example I had "Programms" and "Abbreviations" with the tag "Intro".

So I could easily structure the wiki and I could create an hierarchy.

This feature you can recreate in the new Tiddly wiki doing like this:

```
<<list-links "[tag[Intro]]">>
```

or

```
<<list-links filter:"[tag<currentTiddler>] +[sort[title]]">>
```

or

```
<<list-links "[all[current]tagging[]]">>
```

But this is annoying.
I have to copy this in every tiddler.

Is there an opportunity to get the functionality like in classic? (out of the box).
Maybe by adding something in template?

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035771/tiddlywiki-make-a-list-of-all-tiddlers-tagged-with-name-of-current-tiddler

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 10 times.

Answer (score -1):

- create a tiddler named for exampe `MyTagging` (name doesn't matter)
- tag it with tag:
  `$:/tags/ViewTemplate"`
- in text body write

```
<<list-links "[all[current]tagging[]]">>
```